# Eclipse console stacktrace links to wrong project

Tags: eclipse

I am running multiple projects in my workspace. I have two glassfish servers set up. Project A and Project B both have similar class structures. When Project A hits an exception the console shows the stacktrace and each hyperlink properly links to the file in Project A. However while running Project B, if the exception happens in a class that is in  both projects, eclipse with wrongly link to the Project A class.

Is there anyway to fix this?